# EFCore 6. Как работает метод Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть какая-то таблица, у которой есть FK к другой таблице.
Данный метод возвращает статистику игрока. С помощью ключа я нахожу игрока, а затем беру его статистику(другая таблица).

```
public Statistic GetStatisticFromPlayer(int playerId)
{
      //return _context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == playerId).Statistic; не будет работать, ибо statistic == null
      return _context.Players.Where(p => p.Id == playerId).Select(p => p.Statistic).FirstOrDefault(); 
 }
```

Первый вариант будет возвращать null , ибо у данного объекта не будет проинициализировано поле Statistic(другая таблица), а с помощью метода Select объект Statistic вернется.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как под капотом работает метод Select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот запрос:

```
_context.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == playerId).Statistic;
```

работает следующим образом. Метод `FirstOrDefault` является заключительным в цепочке вызовов. После его выполнения из БД будет получен `Player`. А уже на клиенте будет взято свойство `Statistic`.

SQL-запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT TOP(1) -- колонки Players
FROM Players p
WHERE p.Id = @playerId
```

Как мы видим, запрос не содержит информации из таблицы Statistic.

По умолчанию EF Core не выполнляет загрузку данных из связанных таблиц.
Можно осуществить эту загрузку тем или иным образом: [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).
Самый распространённый способ - Eager loading - энергичная загрузка.
Добавим в запрос `Include`:

```
_context.Players.Include(p => p.Statistic).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == playerId).Statistic;
```

Это приведёт к генерации такого запроса:

```
SELECT TOP(1) -- колонки Players и колонки Statistic
FROM Players AS p
INNER JOIN Statistic AS s ON p.Id = s.PlayerId
WHERE p.Id = @playerId
```

Будет произведено объединение (JOIN) двух таблиц и получены данные из обеих таблиц.

Это даст желаемый результат: значение свойства `Statistic` будет содержать объект.
Однако, если кроме этого объекта другие данные (объект Player) не нужны, то этот запрос получается неэффективным: он запрашивает и материализует лишние данные.

Этот ваш запрос:

```
_context.Players.Where(p => p.Id == playerId).Select(p => p.Statistic).FirstOrDefault();
```

генерирует следующий SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) -- колонки Statistic
FROM Players AS p
INNER JOIN Statistic AS s ON p.Id = s.PlayerId
WHERE p.Id = @playerId
```

Как можно видеть, тут из БД возвращаются данные только Statistic. Если данные Player не нужны, то этот запрос эффективнее предыдущего.

---

SQL-запросы, которые уходят в БД можно смотреть разными способами. Вероятно, самый простой - использовать [Simple Logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#configuration).

В методе `OnConfiguring` добавляем строку:

```
optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
```

Параметр `LogLevel.Information` отсечёт ненужную служебную информацию. Без него будет слишком много шума.

---

Я исходил из предположения, что используется Sql Server, хотя это не важно.
Сгенерированные sql-запросы я вручную очистил от лишних скобок и прочего.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Очень помогли